# r shiny - How to display a variable number of numeric inputs

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to display a variable number of inputs based on a numeric input "number of lines". As there can be potentially a large number of lines, I don't want to use a conditional panel for each line and would rather iterate with functions as below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  lapply(1:3,function(iter1){
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
             h4(paste0("line", iter1))
      ),
      lapply(1:4,function(iter2){
        column(2,
               h4(paste0("Wind speed bin", iter2)),
               column(6, numericInput(paste0("v", iter1,"bin",iter2,"min"),"Vmin",5)),
               column(6, numericInput(paste0("v", iter1, "bin",iter2,"max"),"Vmax",6))
        )
      })
    )
  })  
)
```

The code above allows to display 4 wind speed bins definitions per line j (numericInput: vjbin1min, vjbin1max, vjbin2min, vjbin2max, ...) on 3 lines.

[Overview of sidebar layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF0fH.png)

I would like now to define the number of bins [of lines] with a variable bin_nb [line_nb] as below:

```
lapply(1:bin_nb,function(iter1){...
lapply(1:line_nb,function(iter2){...
```

With two numeric inputs

```
numericInput("bin_nb","number of wind speed bins",value=4),    
numericInput("line_nb","number of lines",value=3)
```

I have tried to get the value from server side

```
output$bin_nb <- renderText(input$bin_nb)
```

And use

```
lapply(1:textOutput("bin_nb"),function(iter1){...
```

Which is of course not working as a numeric value is requested. How could I define and use these two numeric variables bin_nb and line_nb?

Comment: use `renderUI()`,....

Comment: I tried `output$bin_nb <- renderUI(1:input$bin_nb)` on server side to create the list and   `lapply(uiOutput("bin_nb"),function(iter1){` on ui side. It does not work, uiOutput("bin_nb") does not give the right format. Any other clue?

Comment: I tried to define everything in server side with renderUI `output$input_panel <- renderUI({ `and simply call uiOutput("input_panel") on ui side. It works, thanks a lot!

Comment: sometimes a little pointer is enough :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on BigDataScientist's comment, here is the detailed solution:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("line_nb","number of lines",value=3),
  numericInput("bin_nb","number of wind speed bins",value=4),
  uiOutput("input_panel")
)
```

And server side:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$input_panel <- renderUI({

    lapply(1:input$line_nb,function(iter1){
      fluidRow(
        column(2,
               h4(paste0("line", iter1))
        ),
        lapply(1:input$bin_nb,function(iter2){
          column(2,
                 h4(paste0("Wind speed bin", iter2)),
                 column(6, numericInput(paste0("v", iter1,"bin",iter2,"min"),"Vmin",5)),
                 column(6,numericInput(paste0("v", iter1, "bin",iter2,"max"),"Vmax",6))
          )
        })
      )
    })
  })    
}
```